# Parse - Saving multiple images in the same object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a class in `Parse.com` with name Objects. This class contains many fields and also contains 10 `ParseFile` fields which are images. I am using the follow code in order to add a new item in class Objects.

```
ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Objects");
object.put("field1", "test1");
object.put("field2", "test2");

int imagesSize = Details.getInstance().getImages().size();
for (int i = 0; i < imagesSize; i++) {

   //convert bitmap to byte[]
   Bitmap bmp = Details.getInstance().getImages().get(i);
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
   byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

   //convert byte[] to parse file
   ParseFile file = new ParseFile("objectImage.png", data);
   file.saveInBackground();
   object.put("image" + numbers[i], file);
}
object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
         Log.i("Add", "done");
      }else{
         Log.i("Add", e.getMessage());
      }
    }
});
```

My problem is that I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile
```

I know that I should use the below in order to save a `ParseFile`

```
//convert bitmap to byte[]
Bitmap bmp = Details.getInstance().getImages().get(i);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

//convert byte[] to parse file
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("objectImage.png", data);
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
           object.put("image" + numbers[i], file);
      }else{
             Log.i("Add", e.getMessage());
      }
   }
 });
```

but now with multiple images I don't know how to implement. If I use the `saveCallBack` inside `for loop` then I won't get the correct result.

Comment: save image in different different field and you are save image in only one field name is "image" so its not save multiple image.

other wise store first parse file array list then save all parse file and get call back.

Answer (score 1):

//Create photo array column in Parse table.

[image]

// you add multiple phots same time.
// here is array list you must need to add ParseFile object

```
gameScore.addAllUnique("photos", Arrays.asList(parsefilephotoobject1, parsefilephotoobject2,parsefilephotoobject3));
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

// you add single photo one by one in photos Array.
 I have use glide to get byte array from image.
 destination_profile is file object that i select from gallery.

```
  if (destination_profile != null) {
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(destination_profile.getAbsolutePath()).asBitmap().toBytes().centerCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(new SimpleTarget<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(byte[] resource, GlideAnimation<? super byte[]> glideAnimation) {


                    final ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(destination_profile.getName(), resource);
                    parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            gameScore.addUnique("photos", parseFile);
                            gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    showToast("Profile image upload success");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
     }
```

You can get ParseFile Array Object using this

```
@ParseClassName("YourTableName")
public class YourTableName extends ParseObject {


    public static ParseQuery<YourTableName> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(YourTableName.class);
    }



    public List<ParseFile> getParseFilePhotos() {
        return getList("photos");
    }


}
```

Comment: Ok! that's sound good. But I haven't create the database and I haven't any permission to changing the database.

Comment: @user4292106 No issue, you don't need to create database, you just add ones file similar i have explain you, it will automatically create photos array object in that table. just try once

Comment: I mean that the database hasn't been created by me. You tell me //Create photo array coulum in Parse table. I am telling that I haven't got permission for any change in database or table..

Comment: Using code it will automatically create that column

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, but I haven't permission to add a new column in table.

Comment: then wait for permission not any other solution.

Comment: this can't be happen

Comment: Working fine for me.
Thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you need to be saving the files synchronously. This is because you are dependent on the `ParseFile`s being saved and then adding them to your `ParseObject`.

Change your `file.saveInBackground` to `file.save()` (I believe that's the call. You might need to look it up). This way you know they have saved and they are ready to be added to your `ParseObject`.

You can still save your `ParseObject` asynchronously as your not depending on it being saved in code further down the line.

Comment: I have just test with save instead of saveInBackground but I am getting this error  com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure with caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. The ParseObject was saved but the image doesn't

Comment: How big is your `ParseFile` and how good is your internet connection? It sounds like it's timing out because the `ParseFile` is too large.

Comment: The size of image is 1.09 MB

Comment: That should be fine then unless you are testing on a bad internet connection? This is actually a different issue to the one you saw before. You will need to get this working to proceed.

Comment: My internet connection is fine.. I am able to get the Location of the same screen. I just said an example in order to ensure my internet connection

Comment: What do you mean by 'Location' of the same screen? The `ParseObject` is going to be a lot smaller than your `ParseFile` which is why it uploads ok.

Comment: Ok! I mean that from the same screen the user is able to upload the photo and also to define his current location. I just refer the location in order to ensure that the internet connection is fine.

Comment: You can't use getting the location as a way of checking your internet connection. You need to test its speed by using speedtest.net or something.

Comment: Ok! But it is a mobile application and the wifi icon is full therefore how will know a common user that he hasn't good connection?

Comment: Just because the WiFi icon is full doesn't mean your internet connection is quick it just means your connection to WiFi is strong. You are going to need to handle this exception and either proceed regardless or try again later.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, but the whole parseObject is uploading except from the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104407/discussion-between-disco-s2-and-user4292106).